# Change column order on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a site http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/graffitx-2/#jak-dziala where I have sections with columns consisting of images and text, but every second is reversed in order. So 1-row is image-text, next row is text-image, 3rd image-text and 4th, again text-image. On regular pc screen this looks nice, but on mobile where everything should be in one column, the order becomes image-text-text-image-image-text... (instead of image-text-image-text...). Any nice way of defining the responsive column order? Thx.

Comment: Go look into flexbox' `order` property.

Comment: Ok, played with that. I added a flex-container class to my section which consist of elements I want to reorder with css `dislay: flex` property. Then I wanted to test reordering the first two images in that section addidn to my css `flex.container img:nth-of-type(1) { order: 2;} flex.container img:nth-of-type(2) { order: 1; }`. However both images get the first property as the `nth-of-type` would not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Impossible to say without proper example code. Please edit the question.

Comment: Also, tries with other elements, text this time. Added `.flex-container h2:nth-of-type(1) span { order: 2; }
.flex-container h2:nth-of-type(2) span { order: 1; }` which makes the `nth-of-type`assignment proper, but the h2 paragraphs do not get reversed. Looking at code inspection on the site [link](http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/gotouch/) you will find the place looking for the above properties.

Comment: You can not rearrange elements at arbitrary levels inside a flexbox container, they have to be flex items.

Comment: "...have to be flex items" - meaning what? I thought that any element within the flex-container is a flex element that can be modified with flex-kind css. Wrong?

Comment: Only the children are flex items.

Comment: Children in this case - you mean if my `flex-container` is assigned to a section div element, only other divs within this parent div can be flex-items and not p, h or img elements?

Comment: May I suggest that you go read up on the basics of flexbox a little bit? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance - I'm not a developer :) Although I have read this article and couple others. That's what I understood: a flex-container is any element with a flex-parent property (eg. `display: flex`), making all other elements within the parent enclosure "potential" flex-item children that can be styled with any flex-kind properties, eg. `order`.

Comment: `.flex-container h2:nth-of-type(1) span` - now if `.flex-container` is your flex container, then the h2 is a flex item. The spans inside the h2 are not affected at all - to make them flex-items, _their_ parent needs to become a flex container first.

Comment: Ok, understand now how adding `span` made it wrong. However when I put only `.flex-container h2:nth-of-type(1)` it also does not rearrange the h2s :( And THANKS for your time on this...!

Comment: Please put relevant code into the question.

Comment: Cannot  provide code @CBroe, as the site is a Wordpress site. I can assign CSS classes to sections, rows, and single items and then style it with custom css. My current setup here [link](http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/gotouch/#jak-dziala) are rows consisting of an image (1) and text - heading (2) and text (3). Every second row is reversed. On mobile this gets displayed like: 1-2-3 - 2-3-1 instead of 1-2-3 - 1-2-3. I added `flex-container` class to the section div and then the `order` property on the images (1) and text elements (2, 3), but order didn't change.

Comment: Basically this is somewhat what I'd like to achieve modifying order of elements in table. See here [http://codepen.io/kriana/pen/EgqRjE](http://codepen.io/kriana/pen/EgqRjE)